# Xamarin RefreshView causing Tapped Event conflicts on UWP

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I have a multi-platform Xamarin project with a MainPage (called OVerviewPage) that has multiple FlexLayouts with each one bound to a different BindableLayout.ItemSource. The BindableLayout.ItemTemplate for each is a ContentView with each of them formatted similarly but each having a different ViewModel.Model. Each of those ContentViews has its own <Frame.GestureRecognizers> TapGestureRocgnizer calling a Tapped event handled in the code behind. These Flexlayouts are wrapped in a ScrollView which is also wrapped in a RefreshView. The intent is for the user to click on one for the ContentViews to be taken to a details page. The problem is that the RefreshView causes a conflict when compiled for UWP on a windows Desktop.  The problem is that after scrolling down the list and the user clicks on a ContentView the TappedEvent handler of a different ContentView will be called, not the one the user actually clicked on. In fact, when the form first loads 3 ContentViews are visible on the screen, when others are scrolled to and reside in a place over where one of the first 3 were, only a tapped event of one of those first 3 will respond to a click, depending where on the screen where the user clicked. When I comment out the RefreshView in xaml, the clicks work as expected.
I understand that the RefreshView is not designed for desktop units and I tried to disable it using: if(Device.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Desktop){refreshview.IsEnabled = false} but that doesn't work. The mere fact that it is identified in the xaml causes the conflict.
A couple considerations: This page is the main page of a Shell application and any solution will need to take that into consideration. I am also open to most any solution that solves this. Thanks in advance

My OverviewPage: (only the code that is relavant)

```
            <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
                     RefreshColor="Teal"
                     Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Margin="10,0,10,0">
                    
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                                Wrap="NoWrap"
                                AlignItems="Stretch"
                                AlignContent="Center"
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TrackWarrants}"
                                BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TrackWarrantTemplate}" 
                                BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyWarrantTemplate}"/>
                                 
                    <!--Form As-->
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                            Wrap="NoWrap"
                            AlignItems="Stretch"
                            AlignContent="Center"
                            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormAs}"
                            BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FormATemplate}" 
                            BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyFormATemplate}"/>
                    
                    <!--Form Bs-->                      
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                                Wrap="NoWrap"
                                AlignItems="Stretch"
                                AlignContent="Center"
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormBs}"
                                BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FormBTemplate}" 
                                BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyFormBTemplate}"/>

                    <!--Form Cs-->
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                                Wrap="NoWrap"
                                AlignItems="Stretch"
                                AlignContent="Center"
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormCs}"
                                BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FormCTemplate}" 
                                BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyFormCTemplate}"/>
```

ContentViews Code: (only 1 for example they are all the same except for the data placement)

```
    <ContentView.Content>
    <Frame>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding}" Tapped="FormA_Tapped" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

        <Grid  >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="95"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                         Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="130" >
                <Label FontFamily="Material" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Icon}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <Label.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Reject},Path=Text}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Label.Triggers>
                </Label>
                <Label  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" x:Name="FormID">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{Binding FormNumber}"/>
                            <Span Text="-"/>
                            <Span Text="{Binding LineNo}"/>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                    <Label.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Reject},Path=Text}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Label.Triggers>
                </Label>
                <StackLayout.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Reject},Path=Text}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Salmon"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </StackLayout.Triggers>
            </StackLayout>
            
            <Label Text="{Binding Territory}" 
               FontSize="Small"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

            <Label FontFamily="Material" 
               FontSize="Small" 
               Text="{x:Static md:MaterialDesignIcons.MyLocation}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="0"  />

            <Label Text="{Binding From}" 
               FontSize="Small"     
               Grid.Column="3"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />

            <Label FontFamily="Material" 
               FontSize="Small" 
               Text="{x:Static md:MaterialDesignIcons.LocationOn}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="1" />

            <Label Text="{Binding End}" 
               FontSize="Small"   
               Grid.Column="3"    
               Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  />
            
            <Label FontSize="Small"  
               FontAttributes="Bold" 
               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="2"   
               Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="Speed: "/>
                        <Span Text="{Binding Speed}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>

            <Label x:Name="Reject" Text="{Binding Rejected}" 
               FontSize="Small"                  
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="3" IsVisible="False" />
            <Label x:Name="status" Text="{Binding StatusID}" 
               FontSize="Small"                  
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="3" IsVisible="False" ></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Relevant Code Behind for ContentView:

```
        public FormACard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        formaviewmodel = new FormAViewModel();
        BindingContext = formaviewmodel;
    }
    private async void FormA_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = App.LoggedInUser.UserName;

        var ea = e as TappedEventArgs;
        if (ea.Parameter != null)
        {
            var forminfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ea.Parameter);
            string _forminfo = Uri.EscapeDataString(forminfo);
            FormA forma = (FormA)ea.Parameter;
            bool rejectAck = forma.RejectionAcked;
            bool rejected = forma.Rejected;
            string requestor = forma.RequestedBy;
            if (!rejectAck && rejected && requestor == user)
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(RejectACK)}?{nameof(RejectACK.Contentx)}={_forminfo}");
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"viewforma?Content={_forminfo}");
            }

        }
    }
```

FYI - In case this looks familiar, I posted this problem in another thread when I had less information. I closed the other one and open this one with fresh information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that after scrolling down the list and the user clicks on a ContentView the TappedEvent handler of a different ContentView will be called, not the one the user actually clicked on.

About "Xamarin RefreshView causing Tapped Event conflicts on UWP", I found this on GitHub: [[Bug] Wrong behavior using BindableLayout wrapped by a RefreshView](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13631). The link mentions：

> Tested this based on your repro. Found out that its not related to the BindableLayout: you can eliminate it completely, just creating 20 frames directly and it results in the same misbehavior. It seems that - as soon as RefreshView (UWP RefreshContainer) is used - tap events are dispatched to wrong UI controls and/or that scroll offset is not considered correctly.
> Not sure currently if this is an XF bug or an issue in UWP RefreshContainer, even though I didn't find a matching issue (after short search).

If `RefreshView` does not affect the operation of your entire program, you can remove it. Otherwise you can wait for the bug to be fixed.

Wish it can help you.

Comment: Sun, while that is not the answer I was hoping for, it certainly gives clarity to why I'm seeing this problem and can't find a way to overcome it. Since this OverviewPage is shared in all 3 projects, the RefreshView is a necessity it the other 2. So an option to overcome this is to place a new Overview Page, without the RefreshView, in the UWP project folder. Since this is a Shell project I would need to hide the Phone's Shell tab when this is built. If you know of a way to do that, it will help. Otherwise I'll open a new thread. Thanks for your help